# How do you find out all dynamic LDAP groups a user is part of?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, directory-server

Suppose that a user is part of 2 or more **dynamic groups**. How do I query for a list of all groups a user is part of? I have already checked answers where people speak of static groups which have a 'member' attribute. I found no answer for dynamic groups.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic groups are no different from static groups except that dynamic group membership is generated upon request, not stored in the database (on most servers). Therefore, use the same method for getting group membership. This might be using `member`, `memberOf`, `isMemberOf`, or something else entirely, depending on the server.

An example:

```
ldapsearch --hostname hostname --port port                     \
       --baseDN 'dc=example,dc=com' --bindDN cn=RootDN         \
       --bindPasswordFile 'fileWithPassword' --searchScope sub \
       '(uid=username-youre-looking-for)' isMemberOf
```

This (refactored for your installation) will return a search result containing the DN of the user, and a list of `isMemberOf` attribute (each with DN syntax) that will be the DN of the groups of which the user is a member.

Comment: Is this really true? A dynamic group's *own* member attributes (e.g. roleOccupant, uniqueMember, ...) are generated dynamically but retrieved in the normal way, of course, but, if the *user* object has 'memberOf' attributes, are they really generated dynamically? That would seem to require evaluating every dynamic group in the DIT for possible membership ... seems expensive.

Comment: It's certainly true in some servers, hence 'dynamic'.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. I know that a dynamic group's own members as expressed In its own attributes are, err, dynamic. I'm asking about the reverse situation, where a user contains its own memberships and where he may be a member of dynamic groups.

Comment: OK. You are asking about the memberOf or isMemberOf attribute in the user entry. The answer is the same, in some servers those attributes are generated upon request and are not stored in the user entry. The trade-off in those cases is that for databases containing tens of millions of entries (the ones I deal with most often), less storage is used by calculating the group membership dynamically vs. a slight calculation penalty.

Comment: Thanks. How is it 'slight'? Surely the server has to (a) find all the dynamic groups and then (b) all their members to determine which dynamic groups should be in the `memberOf`/whatever attribute? ... bearing in mind that this process is going to mostly generate non-matches.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the server in question. Some servers will maintain groups in parallel in a thread group. It's 'slight' because in my tests this difference between creating dynamic attributes vs. sending back stored attributes in the case of group membership is negligible under load.

Comment: Negligible in the case of 'memberOf? Sorry to keep hammering this, but I want to be sure we are talking about the same thing. I don't understand your statement about 'groups in parallel in a thread group' either. It sill appears to me to require the explosion I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, negligible. The servers I work with show a negligible expansion time for dynamic/virtual attributes, including 'isMemberOf' and 'memberOf'. A well-written, professional-quality server will use multiple threads for management of data, including group management. I measured the difference between retrieving an attribute stored with an entry and an attribute created upon request (memberOf, isMemberOf) (attribute value length: 18 characters) and found the difference to be about 120 microseconds on average (measured at the client) with a standard deviation of 0.12. For me, that's negligible.

Comment: Hi Terry, Thank you very much for your response. This is the command I tried in my ldap server to get the list of all static and dynamic groups a user is part of --> `ldapsearch -h hostname -p Port -D BindDN -w Password -b SearchBase '(uid=UID-I-AM-Looking-For)' isMemberOf` .  However, in the search result I see only static groups listed and not dynamic groups. Are listing of groups dependent on the LDAP server. Do all LDAP servers list both static and dynamic groups in such queries?

Comment: @coder did you find an answer to your question in the end? I've got a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762149/openldap-dynamic-groups-not-searching-by-member).

Comment: @DrJoe , No I didn't find an answer for this. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @coder, yes I did. You can't! The contents of a dynamic group are generated when the data set it returned, so isn't available to search on. The solution is to use the 'autogroup' overlay, which maintains the static membership as the LDAP database is modified.