# How to set autogroup in openLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I try setting autogroup in openLDAP. I added module

```
ldapsearch -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -QY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=module{0},cn=config
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}back_mdb
olcModuleLoad: {1}memberof.la
olcModuleLoad: {2}refint.la
olcModuleLoad: {3}autogroup.la
```

added overlay:

```
dn: olcOverlay={2}autogroup,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAutomaticGroups
olcOverlay: {2}autogroup
olcAGattrSet: {0}groupOfURLs memberURL member
```

I created group:

```
dn: cn=wusers,ou=wiki,ou=Services,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectclass: groupOfURLs
cn: wusers
memberURL: ldap:///ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com??one?(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(!(memberof=cn=groupname,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com)))
```

But I do requesting group then it empty.

I see [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762149/openldap-dynamic-groups-not-searching-by-member), but did not help.

I testing on Debian 9 slapd version 2.4.44.

Comment: You 'do requesting group' how?

Comment: @EJP ldapsearch -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -xWD "uid=user.name,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com" -b dc=domain,dc=com cn=wusers